# Python 3 font usage

Tags: python, text, fonts, widget

I am writing a large project in Python 3.4.1 (using Spyder / Anaconda).  Part of the project is to create a text window, and write to it in different fonts.  For example, I might want to see this in the window: "...and lead me not into temptation..." with only the word 'not' in italics.  None of the Python 2 examples will work.  Can someone offer a code snippet to accomplish this?

Comment: And what are you relying on for your windowing? Answering that pretty much also answers the "which project's documentation to check/API to read up on" in order to find out how to do what you need.

Comment: What do you mean "none of the python 2 examples will work"? What examples, and what errors are you getting? This is extremely easy to do with Tkinter, and anything you can do in python 2 with Tkinter you can do with python 3, the interfaces are identical except for the names of the modules.